# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at App.js:91:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sql-server

I get the error when I try to send de data to the backend by clicking on an activity. Activities are the buttons that render to the client so when the client clicks on any activity, it sends the timestamp of the current time on the timer to the backend. The error occurs each time I press on a different activity the error shows up and then it wont let me click on the same activity more than once to send the data to the server of the same activity again.

Front-end:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './timer.css';


function Timer() {
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [isConfirmationOpen, setIsConfirmationOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState(null);


// start/stop the timer
  const handleStartStop = () => {
    if (isRunning) {
      setIsConfirmationOpen(true);
    } else {
      setIsRunning(true);
    }
  };

//close confirm dialog
  const handleConfirmation = (confirmed) => {
    setIsConfirmationOpen(false);

    if (confirmed) {
      setIsRunning(false);
      setTime(0);
    } else {
      setIsRunning(true);
    }
  };

//format time to 00:00:00
  const formatTime = (time) => {
    const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
    const seconds = time % 60;

    return `${String(hours).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(minutes).padStart(
      2,
      "0"
    )}:${String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  };

//obtain data to show to the client
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/activities')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setActivities(data);
      });
  }, []);

 //increment timer
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;

    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [isRunning]);

  //Send timestamp to server
useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedActivity) {
    let timestamp = formatTime(time);

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ timestamp }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/activities', options)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Error en la solicitud al servidor');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {

        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error al enviar el tiempo:', error);
      });
  }
}, [selectedActivity]);

//When an activity gets clicked:
  const handleActivityClick = (activitiy) => {
    setSelectedActivity(activitiy)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button id='return'>Regresar</button>

      <div id='header'>
        <div id='time'>{formatTime(time)}</div>

        <button
          id='start-stop'
          onClick={handleStartStop}
          style={{ backgroundColor: isRunning ? "red" : "green" }}
        >
          {isRunning ? "Finalizar" : "Iniciar"}
        </button>

        {isConfirmationOpen && (
          <div id='confirm-dialog'>
           <p>¿Está seguro de que deseas finalizar el cronómetro?</p>
            <div id='dialogbtn-container'>
              <button onClick={() => handleConfirmation(true)}>Confirmar</button>
              <button onClick={() => handleConfirmation(false)}>Cancelar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      {isRunning && (
        <div id='activity-container'>
          {activities.length === 0 ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : (
            activities.map((activity, key) => (
              <button className='activity' key={key} onClick={() => handleActivityClick(activity)}>
                {activity.name}
              </button>
            ))

          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

Controller:

```
export async function saveTime(req, res) {
    try {

      const { timestamp } = req.body; // Obtain value from the request body

      const id = uuidv4(); // Generate unique ID

      const pool = await getConnection();
      const result = await pool
        .request()
        .input("id", id) 
        .input("timestamp", timestamp)
        .query(queries.saveTime); //Query:INSERT INTO Test (id, timestamp) VALUES (@id, @timestamp)
      res.json(result.recordset);
      
      console.log(timestamp);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al guardar el tiempo:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al guardar el tiempo" });
    }
}
```

app.js (backend):

```
//express app configuration
import express from 'express'
import router from './routes/routes';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express()

//port
app.set('port', 4000)

//middlewares
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());

app.use(router);

export default app;
```

Comment: First step in debugging: determine what goes in and out. In your case, check what you are sending from the front-end and what the back-end is receiving. Since the error says something is wrong with the JSON input the `JSON.stringify` would be my first suspect.

Comment: So what's the code at App.js line 91? Looking at your saveTime function one assumes that your backend is an express app and you're trying to use an async middleware function to deserialize the JSON payload and rewrite request.body for use by your route controllers.